# Created a project running the html but not connecting

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

after running with ctrl+f5 then this happen's simple html code
this comes in debug console
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

I tried googling tried to run with debuggng and every other option
It only work's if i directly run the html file with chrome via file explorer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I HAVE EXPLAINED IT AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE

Comment: You're yelling at a bot. And I have to say that it is very unclear what you're asking. Could you provide additional information. From the text and tags of it it seems like you are trying to run an Html file via VS Code?